# Derivative of $2(1-L)^{1/2} L^{1/2}$

Tags: derivatives

I have never been good at math. How can i derive the top equation to get the last equation at the bottom.

I've checked Wolframalpha and various other derivative calculators and they have different answers to my university tutors answer is in the image.

Any help i would greatly appreciate! 
Thanks

[derive this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwF0N.jpg)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule

Comment: Thanks! i see how it works now

Comment: Please do not put "SOLVED" like this in your title; instead accept the answer to mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$f(L)=2(1-L)^{1/2}L^{1/2}=2[(1-L)L]^{1/2}.$$ Using the chain rule: $$f'(L)=\frac{1}{2}2[(1-L)L]^{1/2-1}\frac{d[(1-L)L]}{dL}=[(1-L)L]^{-1/2}\frac{d[(1-L)L]}{dL}.$$

By the product rule:

$$\frac{d[(1-L)L]}{dL}=-1(L)+(1-L)(1)=1-2L.$$

Substituting:

$$f'(L)=[(1-L)L]^{-1/2}(1-2L)=\frac{1-2L}{\sqrt{(1-L)L}}$$

which you should be able to see is equal to the expression given in the image.

---

Actually we could simplify things here. You want to find the maximizer of $f(L)$. But since $\ln$ is an increasing function, the maximizer of $\ln f(L)$ will be the same as the maximizer of $f(L)$. Now:

$$\ln f(L)=\ln 2+\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln(1-L)+\ln L\right).$$

Taking the derviative of the RHS (which requires only the chain rule):

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{1-L}+\frac{1}{L}\right).$$

You can easily see this is zero when $L=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

By linearity and the product rule
$$\frac{d}{dL}2(1-L)^{1/2}L^{1/2}=2\left(\frac{d}{dL}(1-L)^{1/2}\cdot L^{1/2}+(1-L)^{1/2}\cdot \frac{d}{dL}L^{1/2}\right)$$
Now recall that the derivative of $x^\alpha=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$, so applying this to your situation with $\alpha=1/2$ and applying the chain rule to the first term gives:
$$2\left(\frac{d}{dL}(1-L)^{1/2}\cdot L^{1/2}+(1-L)^{1/2}\cdot \frac{d}{dL}L^{1/2}\right)=2\left(1/2(\color{red}{-1})(1-L)^{-1/2}\cdot L^{1/2}+(1-L)^{1/2
}\cdot 1/2L^{-1/2}\right).$$
Where the red $-1$ comes from the inner derivative $\frac{d}{dL}(1-L)$.

Now collect the terms in a single expression